# Referencing index from a column and adding count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Following my project below, I would like to python to be able to show which date a trade is made. Currently I have done a backtest that shows if price is above average or below average. Is there a way where I can specify in the result on which date is the trade (buy and sell) is done? For example "Buying now at 5.86999 on 2019-5-20". Also is it possible to add count to the trades that I have done?

```
### Purpose of this code is to backtest MACD strategy using 12,26,9. This is a long only strategy
## Below is to import the relevant code and set pandas option
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime as dt
%matplotlib inline
plt.style = 'ggplot'
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

## Identifying which ticker, start date, end date, defining MACD calcs and appending them into dataframe
stock = "FRO" #Input stock ticker
Start_date = '2019-1-1' #Input Start date for analysis
End_date = dt.datetime.today()
Quick_EMA = 12
Slow_EMA = 26
Signal_EMA = 9
df = web.DataReader(stock,'yahoo',Start_date,End_date)
df['12EMA'] = df['Close'].ewm(span = Quick_EMA, min_periods = Quick_EMA).mean()
df['26EMA'] = df['Close'].ewm(span = Slow_EMA, min_periods = Slow_EMA).mean()
df['MACDLine'] = df['12EMA'] - df['26EMA']
df['Signal_Line'] = df['MACDLine'].ewm(span = Signal_EMA, min_periods = Signal_EMA).mean()

##setting rules for backtest, main strategy - MACD Line crossover signal to buy/sell and risk tolerance on 1% bss Adj CLose
pos = 0
realized_pnl = []
buytrades = 0
selltrades = 0
percentchange = []
cut_loss_percent = 0.96
for i in df.index:
    closing_price = df['Close'][i]
    emin = df['MACDLine'][i]
    emax = df['Signal_Line'][i]
    openprice = df['Open'][i]
    if (emin>emax):
        print('MACD higher than Signal')
        if pos == 0:
            bp = closing_price        
            pos = 1
            buytrades =+1
            cut_loss = cut_loss_percent*bp
            print('Buying now at ' + str(bp))
            print('Will cut loss at ' + str (cut_loss))



    elif (closing_price<cut_loss):
            if pos == 1:
               print('Cut Loss at ' + str(cut_loss))
               pos = 0
               selltrades =+1
               print(cut_loss - bp)
               pc = (cut_loss - bp)
               realized_pnl.append(pc)
               return_onper = pc/bp
               percentchange.append(return_onper)

    elif (emax>emin):
        print('MACD is lower than Signal')
        if pos == 1:
            cp = closing_price
            pos = 0
            selltrades =+1
            print('Selling now at ' + str(cp))
            print(cp-bp)
            pc = (cp - bp)
            realized_pnl.append(pc)
            return_onper = pc/bp
            percentchange.append(return_onper)            


if pos == 1:
    print('Still has position in place')
    mtm = (closing_price - bp)
    mtmgainloss = mtm/bp
    percentchange.append(mtmgainloss)




total_realizedpnl = sum(realized_pnl)
print('Realized Pnl '+ str(total_realizedpnl))
All_pnl = total_realizedpnl + mtm
print('Sum of total Pnl ' + str(All_pnl))
sum(percentchange)
```

Below is a snipet of the results

```
MACD higher than Signal
Buying now at 5.869999885559082
Will cut loss at 5.635199890136718
MACD higher than Signal
...
MACD higher than Signal
Still has position in place
Realized Pnl 4.460401210784912
Sum of total Pnl 5.5204016304016115
Out[21]:
0.6354297951321523
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find a workaround this, it might be quite idiocracy but somehow i works :D

```
### Purpose of this code is to backtest MACD strategy using 12,26,9. This is a long only strategy
## Below is to import the relevant code and set pandas option
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime as dt
%matplotlib inline
plt.style = 'ggplot'
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

## Identifying which ticker, start date, end date, defining MACD calcs and appending them into dataframe
stock = "FRO" #Input stock ticker
Start_date = '2019-1-1' #Input Start date for analysis
End_date = dt.datetime.today()
Quick_EMA = 12 #Amend as you like
Slow_EMA = 26 #Amend as you like
Signal_EMA = 9 #Amend as you like
df = web.DataReader(stock,'yahoo',Start_date,End_date)
df['12EMA'] = df['Close'].ewm(span = Quick_EMA, min_periods = Quick_EMA).mean()
df['26EMA'] = df['Close'].ewm(span = Slow_EMA, min_periods = Slow_EMA).mean()
df['MACDLine'] = df['12EMA'] - df['26EMA']
df['Signal_Line'] = df['MACDLine'].ewm(span = Signal_EMA, min_periods = Signal_EMA).mean()
df['MACD_Sig_diff'] = df['MACDLine'] - df['Signal_Line']
df['MACD_Sig_diff_10MA'] = df['MACD_Sig_diff'].ewm(span = 10, min_periods = 10).mean()
df['Date'] = df.index

##setting rules for backtest, main strategy - MACD Line crossover signal to buy/sell and risk tolerance on 4% bss Adj CLose
pos = 0
realized_pnl = []
buytrades = []
selltrades = []
percentchange = []
cut_loss_percent = 0.96 #Stop loss level, if its 5% it will be 100% - 5% = 0.95
for i in df.index:
    closing_price = df['Close'][i]
    emin = df['MACDLine'][i]
    emax = df['Signal_Line'][i]
    openprice = df['Open'][i]
    tradedate = df['Date'][i]
    if (emin>emax):
        print('MACD higher than Signal')
        if pos == 0:
            bp = closing_price        
            pos = 1
            buytrades.append(1)
            cut_loss = cut_loss_percent*bp
            print('Buying now at ' + str(bp) +' at ' + str(tradedate))
            print('Will cut loss at ' + str (cut_loss))



    elif (closing_price<cut_loss):
            if pos == 1:
               print('Cut Loss at ' + str(cut_loss)+' at ' + str(tradedate))
               pos = 0
               selltrades.append(1)
               print('Pnl is ' + str(cut_loss - bp))
               pc = (cut_loss - bp)
               realized_pnl.append(pc)
               return_onper = pc/bp
               percentchange.append(return_onper)

    elif (emax>emin):
        print('MACD is lower than Signal')
        if pos == 1:
            cp = closing_price
            pos = 0
            selltrades.append(1)
            print('Selling now at ' + str(cp)+' at ' + str(tradedate))
            print('Pnl is '+ str(cp-bp))
            pc = (cp - bp)
            realized_pnl.append(pc)
            return_onper = pc/bp
            percentchange.append(return_onper)            


if pos == 1:
    print('Still has position in place')
    mtm = (closing_price - bp)
    mtmgainloss = mtm/bp
    percentchange.append(mtmgainloss)





print('Realized Pnl '+ str(sum(realized_pnl)))
All_pnl = realized_pnl + mtm
print('Sum of total Pnl ' + str(sum(All_pnl)))
print('Pnl in % ' +str(sum(percentchange*100)))
print('The number of buy trades are ' + str(sum(buytrades)))
print('The number of sell trades are '+ str(sum(selltrades)))
```